# what does wrapping a jQuery object with another `$` mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
$('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function() {

var item = this.selectedIndex;
```

why does `selectedIndex` return `undefined` when I wrap `$(this)`

I thought if `this` is already an jQuery object, than nothing will happen when I wrap with redundant `$`

Is there need to check something before wrapping with `$` ?

what does exactly it means to wrap with `$` ?

Comment: `this` inside the handler is the **native DOM node** not a jQuery object. Native DOM nodes have a `selectedIndex` property, jQuery objects do **not**!

Comment: `this` == DOM element `$(this)` == jQuery object, Also - `$(this)[0] === this`

Comment: `this` is a javascript thing, `$(this)` was specifically made for jQuery.

Comment: What will happen if I do $($(this)) meaning I wrap jquery object with jQuery again?

Comment: As you suspected, nothing will happen.